# Python: Formatting multiple values in .format

Tags: python, formatting, format

I tried to use the following statements in a bit of python code. The formatting worked, however, it used the value of current image in all of the placeholders. Why is this the case? If I remove the current image it does the same with expected_time.

```
print expected_time

print "Frame No. {0:06d} Expected: {0:.3f}ms Actual: {0:.3f}ms Difference: {0:.3f}ms".format(currentImage, expected_time, regression_obj.timeFromStart, abs(expected_time - regression_obj.timeFromStart))
```

OUTPUT:

```
Frame No. 000001 Expected: 1.000ms Actual: 1.000ms Difference: 1.000ms - ERROR
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `0` in all of the specifiers, so it only prints the value of the item at 0th position:

```
{0:06d} 
 ^
```

In Python 2.7+ you can remove it completely and for Python 2.6 you need to specify the position manually.
(From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax): Changed in version 2.7: The positional argument specifiers can be omitted, so `'{} {}'` is equivalent to `'{0} {1}'`.)

For Python 2.7+:

```
print "Frame No. {:06d} Expected: {:.3f}ms Actual: {:.3f}ms Difference: {:.3f}ms".format(...)
```

For Python 2.6:

```
print "Frame No. {0:06d} Expected: {1:.3f}ms Actual: {2:.3f}ms Difference: {3:.3f}ms".format(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would work :

```
print "Frame No. {0:06d} Expected: {1:.3f}ms Actual: {2:.3f}ms Difference:{3:.3f}ms".format(currentImage, expected_time, regression_obj.timeFromStart, abs(expected_time - regression_obj.timeFromStart))
```

Your code does not work because you are assigining every placeholder the value 0 which corresponds to CurrentImage .